# Taxonomy page returns 404 page not found

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, taxonomy, slug

I have a custom post type and one custom taxonomy registered for it. The custom post type is called "memory-cards" and the taxonomy is "lesson".For this taxonomy I have create two  terms "english" and "french".

When I go to this url:

```
example.com/lesson/english
```

or

```
example.com/lesson/french
```

Everything goes as expeted and it directs me to archive page or if I create taxonomy.php or taxonomy-english.php.

But when I try

```
example.com/lesson
```

I get page not found error.

My question is if I'm doing something wrong here? Aren't I supposed to get to the archive page for all the "lesson"s?
I have tried these in my register taxonomy arguments:

```
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'lesson' ),
```

and

```
        'rewrite'           => true,
```

but none worked.
I have seen other question similar to this but they are mostly concerned with the terms link rather than the taxonomy link. Also most tutorials discuss the hierarchy of taxonomy rather that the link of taxonomy.

This is the code for creating the taxonomy:

```
    $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Lessons', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Lesson', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Lessons', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Lessons', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Lesson', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Lesson:', 'textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Lesson', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Lesson', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Lesson', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Lesson Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Lessons', 'textdomain' ),
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'lesson'),
);

register_taxonomy( 'lesson', array( 'memory-cards' ), $args );
```

Comment: You have to create taxonomy-lesson.php to make it work

Comment: Are you sure Varsha? Even if that's true and the taxonomy-lesson.php is not there it should go to archive.php

Comment: Have you created archive-memory-cards.php? Since this is your custom post type you have to create dedicated php templates for archive, taxonomy & single

Comment: Yes and it works, but I need a working and "default" link to taxonomy archive.

Comment: Your default links to archive page will be example.com/memory-cards and for taxonomy example.com/lesson/term-name.

Comment: Varsha, do you mind reading the question again? I don't need CPT and term-name link. I need taxonomy link. Thanks for effort though:)

Comment: @agahi Can you post the full code for registering your taxonomy?

Comment: I updated the question and added the code for taxonomy.

Comment: Add `'has_archive' => true` when registering the CPT?

Comment: Sally, Yes I have and it works but the problem is not with CPT and terms, it is with taxonomy.

Comment: Actually, that's the expected behavior — just like the standard `category` taxonomy, you get a `404` page when visiting `http://your-site.com/category/`, because the category slug is not present in the URL. Hence, `http://your-site.com/lesson/` would also throw the same `404` page, unless you set the `has_archive` to `lesson` when registering the CPT. Try it out — but of course, `http://your-site.com/memory-cards/` would no longer work since you override the archive slug via the `has_archive` parameter.

Comment: Excellent Sally CJ. It worked. I changed 'has_archive' to 'lesson' and It worked.

Comment: As you said sally, now /memory-cards isn't working. Is it correct to say that what I need is not possible in WP? Although it works now but if I add another taxonomy that wouldnn't work.

Comment: @agahi Please check my answer. Hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I try
>
> ```
> example.com/lesson
> ```
>
> I get page not found error.

Like I pointed in my comment to your question, that's actually how it works, where the term slug needs to be specified in the URL. That's why `example.com/lesson/english` (term slug is `english`) and `example.com/lesson/french` (term slug is `french`) work, but not `example.com/lesson` (term slug *not* specified).

So one way to make `example.com/lesson` works, is by setting the [`has_archive`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters) parameter to `lesson` when registering the CPT `memory-cards` via `register_post_type()`. For example:

```
register_post_type( 'memory-cards', array(
    'labels'       => array(
        'name'          => 'Memory Cards',
        'singular_name' => 'Memory Card',
    ),
    'public'       => true,
    'has_archive'  => 'lesson',
) );
```

But that also means, `example.com/memory-cards`, which is the default archive URL for your `memory-cards` CPT (when `has_archive` is set to `true`), would no longer display the CPT archive.

To fix that, or to preserve the default archive URL, you can use `add_rewrite_rule()` to add the rewrite rules for `example.com/lesson`, like so:

```
register_taxonomy( 'lesson', 'memory-cards', array(
    'labels'       => array(
        'name'          => 'Lessons',
        'singular_name' => 'Lesson',
    ),
    'rewrite'      => true,
    // ...other args here...
) );

add_rewrite_rule( 'lesson/?$', 'index.php?post_type=memory-cards', 'top' );
add_rewrite_rule( 'lesson/page/(\d+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=memory-cards&paged=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

The second rewrite rule will handle *paged* requests such as `example.com/lesson/page/2/`.